# Why is Genesis 25:17 parenthesized in the ESV?

Tags: genesis, punctuation

Genesis 25:17 is shown as follows in the ESV:

> (These are the years of the life of Ishmael: 137 years. He breathed his last and died, and was gathered to his people.)

Why are there parenthesis around this verse? What aspect of the original language led the translators to add this?

Comment: Because it constitutes a [parenthetical remark](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parenthetical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in the original language of Gen 25:17 requiring such parenthesis.  They are simply a helpful interpretation used by the ESV translators to help readers follow the line/flow of thought.

- V12 introduces one of the 11 "toledoths" = generations, passages in Genesis, in this case, that of Ishmael.
- V13-15 lists Ishmael's 12 sons
- V16 calls these 12 sons, "princes" and that they produced 12 tribes
- V18 tells us where these tribes settled

Thus, the entire passage of V13-18 appears to be about the Ismael's descendants.  However,  V17 inserts a piece of personal information about Ishmael himself and the ESV makes V17 a parenthetical remark.